# How to prevent collapsed DataGrid rows from being deleted?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm sharing an item collection between 2 DataGrids by collapsing some rows in one DataGrid and making them visible in an other.

This works fine, except the bug, that if user presses Ctrl+a and then Del in one of the DataGrid's, the content of the other one gets deleted as well.

I want to change this behavior so only the items visible in the DataGrid where the deletion takes place, are actually deleted.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to hook the [CollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.collectionchanged.aspx) event and check to make sure the OldItems that are being removed were visible. If not, add them back in.

This doesn't feel like a very nice way of doing things. Can you not wrap your original collection with two "views" on it somehow (and I don't mean "view" as in MVVM)? Is it a two-way binding?

Comment: yes, I can do it with 2 collections. But doing it with a single collection seems more elegant. I think, there must be a way to do this the WPF way

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be suppress <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd>:

```
void DataGridView_KeyDown( object sender, KeyEventArgs e ) {
    if ( e.Modifiers == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode ==  Keys.A ) 
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
}
```